# Black bottom/top space in muli monitor screenshot

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, screenshot

When i take screenshot with my dual monitor connected. Generated screenshot add black space below and top of the screenshot (Like this)

[image]

Both monitors are of same resolution (1366 x 768) difference is the physical size of the screen. One is the laptop screen and another is the external monitor.

How can i avoid these black space in screenshots?

I am using Windows Screenshot feature to take screenshot (<kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>PrtSC</kbd>)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution (stupid mistake). Alignment of monitors in display settings were not properly aligned

This alignment caused black spacing in top/bottom of the screen

[image]

So i simply aligned it properly by draggin it and it fixed the issue.

[image]